# How to maintain the order of heatmap sorted by column A in a heat plot of column B

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

My `dataframe` consists of trajectories split into segments. Other columns represent the actual class of a segment, and predicted label for that same segment.

Here I give an example of how it looks like:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import seaborn as sns

data = {'traj_id': [101,102,102,102,102,102,102,102,104,104,104,104,104,104,104,107,107,107,
                    107,107,107,107,107,107,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,109,109,109,109,109,
                    109,112,112,112,112,112,113,113,113,113,114,114,114,114],
 'segment_id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,
                1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,2],
  'actual': [3,0,0,1,3,3,2,2,0,0,4,4,2,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,3,0,0,2,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,2,1,3,3,3,1,1,
             4,4,2,1,4,4,3,0,3,3,2],
  'prediction' :[3,0,1,0,0,3,1,2,1,3,4,2,4,0,3,1,0,4,2,3,0,0,4,2,3,0,0,3,1,1,0,1,2,1,3,3,1,
                 3,1,4,1,4,1,3,1,4,1,4,1,3] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()

  traj_id segment_id actual prediction
0   101       1        3       3
1   102       1        0       0
2   102       1        0       1
3   102       1        1       0
4   102       2        3       0
```

I am doing a plot of the trajectories on `x-axis` and segments on `y-axis`. So I write a custom function, that takes in the `df` and segment's true class represented by `actual` column. This function sorts the segments so that all segments labelled `0` from all trajectories are plotted, following by all segments labelled `1` from all trajectories, and so on. I give the function's code as below:

```py
def plot_spectral(df, column_name):

    plt.style.use(['default'])
    cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(['r', 'b', 'w', 'y', 'c'])
    cmap.set_bad('k')

    plot_data = df.drop_duplicates(['traj_id', 'segment_id'])
    
    plot_data = pd.concat([plot_data[plot_data[column_name].eq(p)]
        .pivot_table(index='traj_id', columns='segment_id', values=column_name) 
    for p in sorted(plot_data[column_name].unique())]).sort_index(axis=1)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
    sns.heatmap(plot_data, vmin=-0.5, vmax=4.5,cmap=cmap, annot=False)
    colorbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
    colorbar.set_ticks([0, 1., 2., 3, 4])
    
    plt.show()
```

Taking the example `df` above, I plot the true class (column `actual`) like so:

```
plot_spectral(df, 'actual')
```

Output:
[image]

I can also plot the prediction in similar way:

```
plot_spectral(df, 'prediction')
```

Output:
[image]

**The Question**

The prediction plot (second) is fine, but not easy for comparison against  the actual labels (first plot), since it is also sorted according to predicted classes `0` then `1`, etc...

So needed a way to modify my function, so that the ordering for true class (`actual`) is maintained throughout. For the prediction plot, it is not required to have `0s` first before `1s`. In the case of the prediction plot, whatever class is predicted for the true class order should be plotted as it is.

This will allow me easily figure out, for example:

- `segment_id = 1` of `traj_id:  102, 104, 107, 108, 114` that are actually `0s` what is each of these predicted as (colour code)?
- `segment_id = 3` of `traj_id: 104, 107` that are actually `0s`, what is each predicted as?
- `segment_id = 2` of `traj_id: 108` is actually a `1`, what is it predicted as?
- `segment_id = 1` of `traj_id:  109, 112, 113`  are actually `1s`, but what is each of these predicted as?
- and so on...

Only maintaining the ordering of first plot (`actual`) in the second plot (`prediction`) would help easily answer this.

How then do I modify my "hard-coded" function to achieve this aim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put *both* `actual` and `prediction` values in the pivot table and then plot either column group or both of them side by side. For this it's best to split data processing and plotting into two separate functions.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import seaborn as sns

data = {'traj_id': [101,102,102,102,102,102,102,102,104,104,104,104,104,104,104,107,107,107,
                    107,107,107,107,107,107,108,108,108,108,108,108,108,109,109,109,109,109,
                    109,112,112,112,112,112,113,113,113,113,114,114,114,114],
 'segment_id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,
                1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,2],
  'actual': [3,0,0,1,3,3,2,2,0,0,4,4,2,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,3,0,0,2,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,2,1,3,3,3,1,1,
             4,4,2,1,4,4,3,0,3,3,2],
  'prediction' :[3,0,1,0,0,3,1,2,1,3,4,2,4,0,3,1,0,4,2,3,0,0,4,2,3,0,0,3,1,1,0,1,2,1,3,3,1,
                 3,1,4,1,4,1,3,1,4,1,4,1,3] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def make_plot_data(df):
    plot_data = df.drop_duplicates(['traj_id', 'segment_id'])
    return pd.concat([plot_data[plot_data['actual'].eq(p)]
                      .pivot_table(index='traj_id', columns='segment_id', values=['actual', 'prediction'])
                      for p in sorted(plot_data['actual'].unique())]).sort_index(axis=1) 

def plot_spectral(plot_data, column_name=None):
    plt.style.use(['default'])
    cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(['r', 'b', 'w', 'y', 'c'])
    cmap.set_bad('k')

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
    if column_name:
        ax.set_title(column_name)
        plot_data = plot_data[column_name]
    sns.heatmap(plot_data, vmin=-0.5, vmax=4.5,cmap=cmap, annot=False)
    colorbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
    colorbar.set_ticks(range(5))
    plt.show()

plot_data = make_plot_data(df)
```

The plot the actual values `plot_spectral(plot_data, 'actual')`:
[image]

or plot the predicted values `plot_spectral(plot_data, 'prediction')`:
[image]

or plot both of them side by side `plot_spectral(plot_data)`:
[image]